# Convert date from csv to Excel 2016

Tags: excel, csv

It's an easy one but I can't figure it out yet, I've tried searching here but didn't find anything.

I have a csv file, and one of the columns represents the date as:

2015-12-04 11:48:04:017

I want Excel to recognize it as date (not just text). How can I do this ?

Thank you !

Comment: The issue is the partial seconds.  You could use this formula `=--LEFT(A1, FIND("}}}", SUBSTITUTE(A1,":","}}}",3))-1)`  A1 is the cell in which the data is.  Then format the cell to any date format desired.

Comment: Thank you very very much ! that helped !

Comment: Mine may have worked but @JustAnotherCoder 's answer is better and should be accepted as the correct one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your string is not properly formatted for date-time value. If the last comma were a dot, Excel would have recognized it as a date-time value:

```
2015-12-04 11:48:04:017     -- bad
2015-12-04 11:48:04.017     -- good
```

If you can use a text editor or a script to correct the CSV file, that would be great. Failing that, you can use a formula in Excel to convert it:

```
=DATEVALUE(LEFT(A1,10))+TIMEVALUE(MID(A1,12,8))
=DATEVALUE(LEFT(A1,10))+TIMEVALUE(MID(A1,12,8)&"."&MID(A1,21,100))
```

This assume the cell A1 contains the text you want to convert. The first formula ignores the fractional seconds to make things shorter. The second formula includes the fractional second.

Comment: I like this.  I was unaware that one could use the fraction of seconds that way.  A version that combines your with my replace `=DATEVALUE(LEFT(A1,10) ) + TIMEVALUE(SUBSTITUTE(MID(A1,12,100),":",".",3))`.  I dislike counting.  But I like yours.